# #if ! SOME_MACROS equivalent with #ifndef SOME_MACROS if SOME_MACROS always has numerical value

Tags: c++, macros, language-lawyer, conditional-compilation

May be this is duplicate, I can't find similar question.

My surprise that, following code works for all three big compiler without error

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    #if !_LIBCPP_VERSION 
        std::printf("_LIBCPP_VERSION not defined");
    #else
        std::printf("_LIBCPP_VERSION defined and equal to %d", _LIBCPP_VERSION);
    #endif

    #ifndef _LIBCPP_VERSION
        std::printf("_LIBCPP_VERSION not defined");

    #else
        std::printf("_LIBCPP_VERSION defined and equal to %d", _LIBCPP_VERSION);

    #endif
}
```

[Link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ErP1ajq4b)

**My question is that:  There check `#if !_LIBCPP_VERSION` - is always similar with `#ifndef _LIBCPP_VERSION` by standard C or C++?**

Comment: No it's not always the same. `#if !_LIBCPP_VERSION` will be true if `_LIBCPP_VERSION` is defined to `0` (but `#ifndef _LIBCPP_VERSION` will not).

Comment: @wohlstad See Link, all Gcc, Clang, Msvc success compiled `#if !_LIBCPP_VERSION`  even _LIBCPP_VERSION not defined.

Comment: That does not contradict what I wrote. Try to use `#define _LIBCPP_VERSION 0` and you'll get a different behavior between the two. I.e. they are not always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent for numerical values.

| `SOME_MACROS` | `#if !SOME_MACROS` | `#ifndef SOME_MACROS` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `x` | True | False |
| `1` | False | False |
| `0` | True | False |
| undef | True | True |

Now, you said you only care about numerical values, so only the middle rows are relevant here. Yet we see a difference in those two rows.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know that for undef macros #if ! SOME_MACROS evaluated to true.
I thought that, it will be compile error.